# An Ideal I of $ \mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ generated by an integer prime, such that $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt 3]/I$ is not an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals, integral-domain

> Find an ideal I of $ \mathbb Z[\sqrt 
> 3]$ generated by an integer prime (i.e. a prime
>   number in $\mathbb Z$) such that $\mathbb Z[
> \sqrt 
> 3]/I$ is not an integral domain.

**Thoughts:** We need to find some prime number that generates an ideal. This ideal should have the property that upon constructing a quotient of its ring, it should exhibit **zero divisors**. If we choose the prime number to be $3$, we consider $I =(\{ 3\})$. Then observe that $$\sqrt{3}=0+ 1 \cdot \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$$
And also that $\sqrt{3}$ is not divisible by $3$ in $\mathbb Z[
\sqrt 
3]$, therefore its residue class modulo 3 will be $\overline{\sqrt{3}}$
$$ \overline{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \overline{\sqrt{3}} =3 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$$
So in  $\mathbb Z[
\sqrt 
3]/(3)$ we observe that there is at least one zero divisor and therefore it cannot be  an integral domain.

I'm fairly new to integral domains and ideals, is this reasoning correct/on point?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The important point is that $\sqrt{3}\not\in I= (3)_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]}$, so $\overline{\sqrt{3}}\not\equiv \overline{0}$, but $\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}=3\in I$ so $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/I$ is not a domain.

Comment: More generally this exact reasoning will work for any prime $p$ in which $3$ is a square, because then the ideal $(p)$ will not be prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ so that the quotient is not a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't fit this in a comment so I will write it here. Your reasoning is correct.

Furhtermore for all primes $p\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{2,3\}$, let $\mathfrak{{p}}=(p)_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]}$.

Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal if and only if $x^2-3$ has no roots modulo $p$, in which case $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.

On the other hand $\mathfrak{p}$ is not prime if and only if $x^2-3$ has a root $r$ modulo $p$ (so it has two roots, $-r$ is the other one), and in this case $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$.

When the prime $p=3$ you will have $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2)$.

When the prime $p=2$ you will have $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/\mathfrak{p}\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/((x-1)^2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2)$.

In other words $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}] = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(p)_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]} \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-3)$